# Redis Cluster Setup with dns

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

**NOTE: I am new to redis cluster setup.**

I am working setting up redis cluster. The cluster setup is complete. However when I want to setup the cluster using dns as follows

```
redis-cli --cluster create redis-01.internal:6379 redis-02.internal:6379 redis-03.internal:6379
```

I get the following errors indicating

```
>>> Nodes configuration updated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> Assign a different config epoch to each node                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Node redis-02.internal:6379 replied with error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ERR Invalid node address specified: redis-01.internal:6379
```

I did also go through few of the similar questions which suggest dns based clustering is not available in redis.

**So, is there any solution or some way to make sure the dns based cluster works for redis.**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Redis doesn't support creating cluster by specifying hostnames; their IPs need to be used instead.